# what's the difference between anchor peer and a gossip leading peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

they're used for cross-org communication in official doc and config-tx.yaml comment, meanwhile we need to specify a anchor peer in docker-compose file, and specify CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true, it's conflict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaders and anchor peers are not very related terms in the context of Hyperledger Fabric.

**Anchor peers** - used to advertise peers from different organization to eventually build up shared membership view of all peers in the channels from all organizations.

**Leaders** - responsible to maintain highly available connection with ordering service to guarantee cluster of peers will be able to make a progress and receive new blocks.

Comment: Thanks, Artem. There is no election for anchor peers, if a anchor peer crash, how to select a peer to take over the work?

Comment: Once network is bootstrapped and peers has build membership view, the failure on anchor peer won't cause a lot of damage. But yes, operators will have to take care to maintain anchor peers highly available in general. Also you can always run config update transaction with new anchor peer endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your help!